# How to use CAP_REWINDPAGE as TWAIN api in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, twain

I want to control the eject direction of paper without UI(Dialog) on A4 Document Scanner.

So I have been tried to use `CAP_REWINDPAGE` API many times.

But it didn't work at all.

1st, When I tried the API during state 4, the error `TWCC_CAPUNSUPPORTED` occurred.

2nd, When I tried the API during state 5 and 6, the error `TWCC_SEQERROR` occurred.

I have used `CAP_FEEDEREBABLED(TRUE)`, `CAP_AUTOFEED(TRUE)`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Comment: Does your scanner support the capability? You can try using this [online demo](https://demo.dynamsoft.com/Samples/dwt/Inspect-TWAIN-Devices-by-Capability-Negotiation/Inspect-TWAIN-Devices-by-Capability-Negotiation.html) to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in advance (by TWACKER, etc) that the requested capability CAP_REWINDPAGE is supported by the particular TWAIN driver? Only few drivers/devices support this non-mandantory capability.